# git diff to review the difference in size of the library

Tags: git

I have checked in shared libraries of my source code. Since I am not interested in the content of the shared library, I would like to review the size of the library before I commit.

Is there any way to review the difference in the size of the HEAD object and the current object?

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv could provide some diffable text, not only size but for example list of exported functions.

Answer (score -2):

NAME
`git-diff -` Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc

SYNOPSIS

```
git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>…​]

git diff [options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…​]

git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]

git diff [options] <blob> <blob>

git diff [options] [--no-index] [--] <path> <path>
```

DESCRIPTION
Show changes between the working tree and the index or a tree, changes between the index and a tree, changes between two trees, changes between two blob objects, or changes between two files on disk.

```
git diff [--options] [--] [<path>…​]
```

This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In other words, the differences are what you could tell Git to further add to the index but you still haven’t. You can stage these changes by using git-add[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

```
git diff --no-index [--options] [--] [<path>…​]
```

This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can omit the --no-index option when running the command in a working tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree controlled by Git.

```
git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…​]
```

This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named . Typically you would want comparison with the latest commit, so if you do not give , it defaults to HEAD. If HEAD does not exist (e.g. unborn branches) and  is not given, it shows all staged changes. --staged is a synonym of --cached.

```
git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named . You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

This is to view the changes between two arbitrary .

```
git diff [--options] <commit>..<commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

This is synonymous to the previous form. If  on one side is omitted, it will have the same effect as using HEAD instead.

```
git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.

Just in case if you are doing something exotic, it should be noted that all of the  in the above description, except in the last two forms that use ".." notations, can be any .

```
git diff [options] <blob> <blob>
```

This form is to view the differences between the raw contents of two blob objects.

for more inoformation click here [More Details](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: I dont know what do you want to achieve by copy and paste the man page.